# Periodically Refresh Items in JList (Java SWING)

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm trying to write some Java code to pull display a list of questions, obtained online. I have a working method called getQuestions, which pulls from my server and builds question objects off of that. I now want a JList that will automatically refresh every few seconds to be up to date on all the questions. If I run updateQuestions not inside the loop, it works fine, but as soon as I put it in the loop the list always shows up blank.

I have a method, called updateQuestions(), which gets the new array list of questions then sets them into the JList. If I run it once, it works fine. However, when I put it in my main as such:

```
listModel=new DefaultListModel();
questionList = new JList(listModel);
questionFeedFrame.add(questionList);
questionFeedFrame.pack();
questionFeedFrame.setVisible(true);
 while(true){
     try{
          updateQuestions(id);
          Thread.sleep(10000);
     }catch (Exception ee){
              ee.printStackTrace();
             }
           }


public static void updateQuestions(int id){
    listModel = (DefaultListModel) questionList.getModel();
    listModel.removeAllElements();
    ArrayList<Question> questions = getQuestions(id);
    for(Question q : questions){
       listModel.addElement(q.getQuestion());
    }
}
```

I've tried a bunch of things, including having everything repaint/validate. Any suggestions? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `Thread.sleep(...)` and `while (true)` loop are both tying up the Swing event thread preventing it from doing its two main jobs of drawing the GUI and interacting with the user. This will effectively *freeze* your GUI.

You could use a Swing Timer to do your loop without tying up the Swing event thread, but this won't fix problems with time needed to get online and download from a server. Thus I recommend that you instead use a background thread for this such as can be found with a SwingWorker, so as not to tie up and freeze the Swing event thread.  Please check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more on this.

Comment: @user2316901: you're welcome, but with a caveat -- be sure to update Swing properties on the Swing event thread only. That's why the SwingWorker is likely the better solution since it has a framework to make this easier to do.